# Apache 2 Module configuration error

Tags: apache2, modules

I'm trying to install [SML Server](http://smlserver.org/) in my machine. After following all the instructions (located [here](http://www.itu.dk/research/mlkit/dist/README_SMLSERVER_BIN-4.3.2.txt) and at this [book](http://www.elsman.com/smlserver-book-20070410.pdf?attredirects=0) at 2.2 chapter) I try to configure Apache by adding a new module like this:

A new `sml.conf` file was added with:

```
<IfModule mod_sml.c>
      AddHandler sml-module .sml
      SmlPrjId "web"
      SmlPath "/usr/lib/smlserver/www/"
      SmlInitScript "/usr/lib/smlserver/web_sys/init.sml"
</IfModule>
```

and the new `sml.load` file with the following data:

```
LoadModule sml-module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_sml.so
```

The `mod_sml.so` library was taken from [here](http://www.itu.dk/research/mlkit/dist/smlserver-4.3.2-i386-ora.tgz).

Then when trying to restart Apache I receive these error message:

```
sudo apache2ctl restart
apache2: Syntax error on line 204 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax
     error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/sml.load: Cannot load
         /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_sml.so into server:
         /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_sml.so: undefined symbol: log
```

Any ideas/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Suggestion: It may help if you add the link to instructions where  you are "following all the instructions".

Comment: @Jamess done :)

Answer (score 1):

1. That package is for 32-bits systems. You're not having that problem, because you do not get a warning about "Wrong ELF class".
2. That package was released 12 April 2007 (according to their [download page](http://smlserver.org/download.sml) and subversion repository).
3. I suspect that the module was built for Apache 2.0.x and not 2.2.x. The next Apache version after 12 April 2007 is [Apache 2.2.6 and 2.0.61](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-announce/200709.mbox/%3CA9C503A2-2023-4D4A-A9F4-6E7F69859E7A@apache.org%3E).

Instructions for building it from source:

1. Install some requirements:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install subversion build-essential apache2-threaded-dev mlton smlnj bison flex
   ```
2. Download the source tree for that version (about 25MB download size, 60MB disk space used after download):

   ```
   svn co https://mlkit.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/mlkit/tags/mlkit-4.3.2/kit mlkit-4.3.2
   ```
3. Start with a prerequisite: mlkit. Run the below commands:

   ```
   cd mlkit-4.3.2
   ./autobuild
   ```
4. - If you do not have a previous mlkit install, run:

     ```
     ./configure
     make nj
     ```

     For some reason, the above steps fails on my machines (64-bit Natty and 32-bit Lucid). The message is:

     ```
     Error: GenOpcodes.sml 20.60.
       Function applied to incorrect argument.
         expects: [<equality>] * [<equality>]
         but got: [<non-equality>] * [<non-equality>]
         in: = (OS.Process.system ("mv " ^ sou  ...   OS.Process.success)
     ```

     If it fails for you too, do not continue.
   - If you do have a mlkit install, run:

     ```
     ./configure --with-compiler=mlkit
     make mlkit
     ```
5. If the previous step completed without fatal errors, continue running the next commands:

   ```
   make bootstrap
   make mlkit_libs
   ```
6. Install to `/usr/local`:

   ```
   sudo make install
   ```
7. Next, the SML server:

   ```
   ./configure --enable-SMLserver --with-apxs="$(which apxs2)" --with-compiler="$(which mlkit)"
   make smlserver
   make smlserver_libs
   ```
8. Install the library:

   ```
   sudo make install_smlserver
   sudo cp /usr/local/lib/smlserver/lib/mod_sml.so /usr/lib/apache2/modules/
   echo "LoadModule sml_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_sml.so" | sudo tee /etc/apache2/mods-available/sml.load
   ```
9. Create the file `/etc/apache2/mods-available/sml.conf` with the following content:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_sml.c>
     AddHandler sml-module .sml
     SmlPrjId "web"
     SmlPath "/home/mael/web/www/"
     SmlInitScript "/home/mael/web/www/../web_sys/init.sml"
   </IfModule>
   #<Directory /home/mael/web/www/web/secret>
   #  SetHandler None
   #  RewriteEngine On
   #  RewriteBase /web/secret
   #  RewriteRule .* pub.sml
   #</Directory>
   ```
10. Enable the module and restart the server:

    ```
    sudo ln -sf /etc/apache2/mods-available/sml.conf /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/sml.conf
    sudo ln -sf /etc/apache2/mods-available/sml.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/sml.load
    sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
    ```

This guide was compiled from:

- https://mlkit.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/mlkit/tags/mlkit-4.3.2/kit/README
- https://mlkit.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/mlkit/tags/mlkit-4.3.2/kit/README_SMLSERVER

Comment: First of all I would like to thank you for your time! Step 3. failed with the same error message as yours, although I have already mlkit install (I don't remember since when), as you can see here: `mlkit -v
MLKit 4.3.2 (rev 2220; 2007-04-12) [X86 Backend]`. Also, are you suggesting that I should downgrade my current Apache 2.2.x version for an older one?

Comment: In that case, could you try the new steps? If it's still fruitless, you could try downgrading Apache, but that'll be your last resort.

Comment: No next steps fail also. Step 7 for example doesn't work because `GenOpcodes.sml` file wasn't compiled. I.e. the errors I get when trying `make smlserver` are: `make[2]: Entering directory '/home/monra/mlkit-4.3.2/src/Tools/GenOpcodes'
/usr/bin/mlkit -output kitgen_opcodes sources.mlb 
Stopping compilation due to errors.
SysErr: No such file or directory [noent]
make[2]: *** [kitgen_opcodes] Error 1`

Comment: I'm out of ideas, sorry. I do not master the SML language, perhaps you can debug that file?

Comment: I tried debugging the file. But unfortunately that created more bugs in other files. Anyway, thank you very much for your time.